# Most cost efficient way to add a third monitor to a system?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a machine that's a couple of years old, but still functional; motherboard Asus P5Q Pro, graphics card Nvidia GeForce 9500 GT.  It's had two monitors since day one, but I now want to add a third.

I've heard about DualHead2Go/TripleHead2Go, but at $380AU, I'm pretty sure that an extra graphics card is a more cost efficient option.  It doesn't have to be the latest fancy-fancy. DVI  is all I need (preferably dual, but I don't have the desk space for four monitors, so it doesn't matter that much), it's a work machine that's more workhorse than powerhouse.

Does anyone have any recommendations for suitable cards?  Or advice on compatibility issues I may run into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are just looking for a cheap way to add an extra monitor and you can not or do not want to purchase a new video card you can always look at some of [these](http://www.usbgear.com/USB-Video-Card.html) USB video cards. The drivers for most that I have seen are only for windows systems and the cards will not be as powerful, but if you are looking for a cheap easy way to add an extra monitor, it is another option besides adding another internal video card.